Appending Tabs to an existing TabView output
I would like to do a kind of versioned TabView for several runs of the same code.
I would like some help in fixing this prototype code:
TabViewAppend[genfun_] := 
Module[{nb, pcell, newcell, tabviewpos, tabcount},
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, 2];
pcell = NotebookRead[nb];
If[MatchQ[pcell, HoldPattern[Cell[BoxData[TabViewBox[__]], __]]],
(* append *)
tabviewpos = First@Position[pcell, TabViewBox[___], All, 1];
tabcount = Extract[pcell, Join[tabviewpos, {1, -1, 1}]];
newcell = 
 Insert[pcell, {tabcount + 1, tabcount + 1 -> ToBoxes[genfun]}, 
 Join[tabviewpos, {1, -1}]];
NotebookWrite[nb, newcell];,
(* new tabview *)
 TabView[{"1" -> genfun}]]]

The purpose of which is

If there is nothing in the next cell, create a tabview with one tab (content is generated by the supplied expression genfun)

If there is already a tabview below, just add a newtab to the right and run genfun again to supply its content.


My trouble : first generation works well. Appending works well but only if I put a blank input cell between the cell containing the call and the initial tabview.
I have played with versions and combinations of SelectionMove without finding the right settings.
I am quite confident the solution exists but I am still searching.
Example usage:
TabViewAppend[Grid@Table[RandomInteger[5, 5], {n, 1, 5}]]


The following code works, but it generates a Input cell instead of a Output cell.
( It works with a "Text" style too, just modify "Input" by "Text" in the code below).
TabViewAppend[genfun_] := 
  Module[{nb, pcell, newcell, tabviewpos, tabcount}, 
   nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
   SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, 1 (* new *)];
   pcell = NotebookRead[nb] ;
   NotebookWrite[nb,
    If[MatchQ[pcell, HoldPattern[Cell[BoxData[TabViewBox[__]], __]] ],
     (*append*)
     tabviewpos = First@Position[pcell, TabViewBox[___], All, 1];
     tabcount = Extract[pcell, Join[tabviewpos, {1, -1, 1}]];
     newcell = 
      Insert[pcell, {tabcount + 1, tabcount + 1 -> ToBoxes[genfun]}, 
       Join[tabviewpos, {1, -1}]],
     (*new tabview*)
     Cell[
      BoxData[TabViewBox[{{1, "\<\"1\"\>" -> ToBoxes[genfun]}}, 1]], 
      "Input" (* or "Text" but neither "Output" neither "Print"*)]]]];  

The origin of your problems is that when you evaluate TabViewAppend["blahblah"] the first time, it generates a cell with the style "Output".
This style says that the cell should automatically be deleted at the next evaluation of the code TabViewAppend["blahblah"].
It turns out that the deletion is done before the evaluation of SelectionMove[nb...].


Interestingly, it works whatever you put in TabViewAppend[] : text,grid, cell, image,video...

The cell options involved by the automatic deletions are CellGenerated and CellAUtoOverwrite. I don't dare to play with that because I have seen on Mathematica SatckExchange that there are very subtles problems.

your modification and slight refactorization will do nicely for my intended use, thanks a lot. The subtlety of Output Cells were making me doubting my sanity.

Interestingly, with slight modifications, the same idea can be used for TableView and TextGrid.
